# Return flag when PMD validation is successful

Tags: clearcase, pmd

i am calling PMD Tool from Clearcase triggers, i want to process based on the reponse from PMD validation. but PMD tool doesnt return any flag or nything back to CC trigger. please help me how can i handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is best to redirect the result (stdout and stderr) of an external tool to a file.

Then the hook (which just called PMD) can read that result file and return its content.